# Running a module on command line gives error : Module target not found

Tags: java, command-line, java-9, java-module

I am new to JAVA9 modular architecture and trying to compile and run module inside a JAR from windows command line.

I have created simple HelloWorld.java main class and project architecture is as below :

[image]

I was successfully able to compile and create JAR file using following command.

Compile :

```
javac -d target/HelloWorld src/HelloWorld/com/java/modularity/test1/HelloWorld.java src/HelloWorld/module-info.java
```

Create a HelloWorld.jar file in "jarfile" directory :

```
jar -cfe jarfile/HelloWorld.jar com.java.modularity.test1.HelloWorld  target/HelloWorld/module-info.class target/HelloWorld/com/java/modularity/test1/HelloWorld.class
```

Getting following error while trying to run module from JAR file :

```
D:\sts_workspace\java9tutorial>java -p jarfile -m HelloWorld
module HelloWorld does not have a ModuleMainClass attribute, use -m <module>/<main-class>
```

Getting following error while slide change in command :

```
D:\sts_workspace\java9tutorial>java -p jarfile -m target/HelloWorld/com.java.modularity.test1.HelloWorld
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module target not found
```

---

Here is my entry class HelloWorld.java :

```
package com.java.modularity.test1;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Testing first HelloWorld module ...");
    }
}
```

Here is HelloWorld module description :

```
module HelloWorld {

}
```

I also tried by extracting my generated HelloWorld.jar file and "Main-Class" attribute is also present in MANIFEST.MF file :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_172 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.java.modularity.test1.HelloWorld
```

Do I need to export the entry class in my module definition ? Any suggestion will help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you create the jar using `1.8.0_172`? Wondering how its there in the manifest. Also what if you export the package including the Main class mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
-m target/HelloWorld/com.java.modularity.test1.HelloWorld
```

to

```
-m HelloWorld/com.java.modularity.test1.HelloWorld
```

for the syntax is *module[/mainclass]*

Comment: I tried the command you have mentioned. But it did not work. New command "java -p jarfile -m HelloWorld/com.java.modularity.test1.HelloWorld" and  Error: Could not find or load main class com.java.modularity.test1.HelloWorld in module HelloWorld .

Comment: Do I need to mention export statement for my HelloWorld entry class ? From error it seems that, VM is searching for the entry class definition in HelloWorld module.

Comment: One more assumption, I am running this program latest jdk 11.0.1 which may have be different version of JAR command. Can it be root of this problem ?

Comment: @GunjanShah running with JDK 11 shouldn't really matter since there is no such code in there which might break even when compiled with a lower version of Java.  I was wondering more on the jar creation part. Also, if you export the package in module-info, does that fix it by any chance?